# U -statistics for bi variate sample problem

Tags: nonparametric, independence, bivariate, u-statistics

Let $(X_1, Y_1), (X_2, Y_2),....,(X_n, Y_n)$ be iid random variables with joint distribution function $F(x, y)$ and $F(x), G(x)$ be the marginal distribution functions of $X_1$ and $Y_1$ respectively. Suppose $F(0)=G(0)=0$. Find a U-statistic estimator of $$\gamma(F, G)=\int_0^{\infty}F(x)dG(x)$$ when (a) $F(x, y) \neq F(x)G(y)$ for some $x, y$ and (b) $F(x, y)=F(x)G(y), \forall x, y$.
$$$$For part (a) we can write $$\gamma(F, G)=\int_0^{\infty}F(x)dG(x)=\int_0^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_1 \leq x)dG(x)=\int_0^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_1 \leq Y_2|Y_2=x)dG(x)=\mathbb{P}(X_1 \leq Y_2)$$. So a symmetric unbiased estimator for $\gamma(F, G)$ is $$h((X_1, Y_1), (X_2, Y_2))=\frac{\mathbf{1}(X_1 \leq Y_2)+\mathbf{1}(X_2 \leq Y_1)}{2}$$ with degree $2$. And so the corresponding U-statistics would be $$U((X_1, Y_1),...., (X_n, Y_n))=\frac{1}{n \choose 2}\sum_{i<j}\frac{\mathbf{1}(X_i \leq Y_j)+\mathbf{1}(X_j \leq Y_i)}{2}.$$ For part (b) $$\gamma(F, G)=\int_0^{\infty}F(x)dG(x)=\int_0^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_1 \leq x)dG(x)=\int_0^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_1 \leq Y_1|Y_1=x)dG(x)=\mathbb{P}(X_1 \leq Y_1)$$ because now $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Now the problem is if we treat $(X_1, Y_1),....(X_1, Y_n)$ as a single sample from the bivariate population $F(x, y)$ then a symmetric unbiased estimator for $\gamma(F, G)$ is $h((X_1, Y_1))=\mathbf{1}(X_1 \leq Y_1)$ and the corresponding U-statistics would be $$U((X_1, Y_1),....,(X_n, Y_n))=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf{1}(X_i \leq Y_i)}{n}.$$ But if we treat the given data as two independent samples from the populations $F$ and $G$, then it will become a two sample problem and a symmetric unbiased estimator for $\gamma(F, G)$ is $h(X_1, Y_1)=\mathbf{1}(X_1 \leq Y_1)$, and the corresponding U-statistics would be $$U(X_1,....,X_n, Y_1,....,Y_n)=\frac{\sum_{i, j=1}^n\mathbf{1}(X_i \leq Y_j)}{n^2}.$$By definition both of them are U-statistics. So which of them is the right one and why?